# How to detect browser force refresh event - Cross Browser

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, dom-events

I want to detect force refresh event  on JavaScript. When user click on browser reload button or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f5</kbd> (on Windows) / <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> (on Mac) and  <kbd>refresh</kbd> on mobile device.

I tried `beforeunload` event but this event trigger on every page load and navigating to other page.

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (event) {
   // This not working exactly what I want.
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I can think of would be [Navigation Timing](https://www.w3.org/TR/navigation-timing/)

The `window.performance` attribute provides a hosting area for performance related attributes.

```js
if (window.performance) {
  if (performance.navigation.type === performance.navigation.TYPE_RELOAD) {
    console.info( "Reload detected" );
  } else {
    console.info( "Reload not detected");
  }
} else {
  console.info("window.performance is not supported");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if (performance.navigation.type == 1) {
        console.info( "This page is reloaded" );
}
```